# Cycle with negative length in a directed graph

Tags: graph-theory

Consider a network $G = (V,A)$. Suppose that node $v_1$ has no incoming arrows and that for every $v_j \neq v_1$ there exists a path from $v_1$ to $v_j$.
Show that $G$ has a cycle with negative length if and only if $x_j ^{n} < x_j ^{n-1}$.
($x_j ^{k}$ is the length of the shortest path from $v_1$ to $v_j$ with at most $k$ arrows.)

I have no idea how to start with this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by negative length ?

Comment: All arrows in $A$ have a value $p$. This value can be positive or negative, so $p \in \mathbb{Z}$. By negative length we mean that the sum of the values of the arrows on the path (cycle) is negative.

Comment: And what is $j$ ?  do you mean that $x^n_j < x^{n - 1}_j$ holds for all $j$ ?  And what is $n$ ?  Is $n = |V|$, or does there exist such a $n$ for every $j$ ?

Comment: $j = 2,3,...,n$, with $n = |V|$. $x_j ^{n} < x_j ^{n-1}$ holds for all $j$.

Comment: Then take a directed path of length $n$, i.e. the graph looks like $v_1 \rightarrow v_2 \rightarrow \ldots \rightarrow v_n$ with each arc of weight 1.  Add the arc $(v_n, v_{n - 2})$ of weight say $-1000n$.  Then the graph has a negative weight cycle $v_nv_{n - 2}v_{n-1}v_n$.  But $x_j^n < x_j^{n - 1}$ does not hold.  Is that right ?

Comment: I understand that in your example the graph has a negative weight cycle. But how can we determine $x_j ^{n}$ and $x_j ^{n-1}$? The length of the shortest path from $v_1$ to $v_n$ is equal to $n$. So $x_j ^{n} = n$ for $j=n$. How about $x_j ^{n-1}$?